# AVSpeechSynthesizer under ios16 not working (same code fine on iOS 12 / iOS 15) on UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, avspeechsynthesizer

This is what I am using for TextToSpeech using `AVSpeechSynthesizer` and it seems to be working from iOS 12 & iOS 15, but when I try it on iOS 16.1, no voice can be heard using the below code.

I have confirmed that Spoken Content is working (Accessibility -> spoken content -> Speak Selection -> Enabled) and I can get the phone to speak out whole screen of text.

However, it's just not working for my app.

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

struct TTS {
  
//  let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

  static func speak(messages: String) {
    let message = "Hello World"

    let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    
    let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: messages)
    utterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate

    utterance.postUtteranceDelay = 0.005
    synthesizer.speak(utterance)
    
  }
}
```

This has helped some, but only for the problem of AVSpeechSynthesizer not working under  Xcode simulator.

[AVSpeechSynthesizer isn't working under ios16 anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73706115/avspeechsynthesizer-isnt-working-under-ios16-anymore)

The other solutions in that SO doesn't seem to be working for my case.

some of the proposed solution is asking to move the `let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()` out of the function, but when I do that, Xcode complains about `Instance member 'synthesizer' cannot be used on type 'TTS'`

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/712809

I think there's possibility something wrong w/ my code for iOS 16

This is for UiKit and not SwiftUI which other SO ( [Swift TTS, no audio-output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74411749/swift-tts-no-audio-output)) has a solution for.

Comment: Your question appears to be already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74411749/swift-tts-no-audio-output), with an answer similar to yours.

Comment: That solution was for SwiftUI which I’ve actually found but mine if UIKit and it has got to do a the way I was  coding it as a struct hence the error. Changing it to a class now makes it behave as it should.

Answer (score 2):

Changed my struct to a class since `AVSpeechSynthesizer` can't be a local variable.
This now works

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class TTS {
  
  let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
  
  func speak(messages: String) {
    print("[TTS][Speak]\n\(messages)")

    let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: messages)
    utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
    
    utterance.postUtteranceDelay = 0.005
    synthesizer.speak(utterance)
  }
  
}
```

How to Use

```
let tts = TTS()
tts.speak(message: "Hello World")
```

Comment: Although your question was for UIKit, it appears to solve the same problem as the other question that I pointed out: the `AVSpeechSynthesizer` went out of scope and was deinit before the speech played. I'd bet that if you simply change your `TTS` class back to a `struct` without changing anything else, it'll still work.

Comment: I did do that. That was the first thing I tried and it's reflected in my question. (the code was commented out) and the error that came out was ```Instance member 'synthesizer' cannot be used on type 'TTS'```

Comment: Yeah, that's because your `speak` method is static, it has to be a member method (like in your answer)

Comment: thanks for the pointer.. removed the ```static``` and it compiles w/o errors. However, using as a struct and calling it as ```TTS().speak(message: "hello")``` yielded no Text To Speech voice being emitted.

Comment: Hmm, that might be due to the `TTS` struct being deconstructed by swift, but now that I look at it, its puzzling why that doesn't happen when `TTS` is a `class`... Either ways, I believe assigning TTS() to a member variable in your UIKit view (or similar) would fix the problem, but if a `class` works for you then by all means continue using it :D

Comment: I just did a minimally reproducible example and using a struct but calling it from a member variable (eg: ```let structTTS = TTS()```)  instead of  ```TTS().speak(messages:"hello")``` works. Swift is somehow immediately deallocating the synth when used as ```TTS()``` but not when it's assigned to a member variable. It's interesting that the previous code works on both iOS12 and iOS15 physical devices.

Comment: It appears that the behaviour with a `struct` is the expected behaviour, but whats puzzling is why that doesn't occur when `TTS` is a `class`.